# Using the Google Web Toolkit or Javascript how do I go about parsing HTML to find an image element and its link?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, html-parsing

I would prefer the answer in GWT but I should be able to translate the Javascript for my purposes.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element has an id, you can use:

```
Element e = com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.getElementById("myImgElementId");
String imageSrc = e.getPropertyString("src");
```

If you're a fan of strong typing, you could also do something like:

```
Element e = DOM.getElementById("myImgElementId");
ImageElement img = ImageElement.as(e);
String imageSrc = img.getSrc("src");
```

Comment: If the original poster was also looking for the link you'd go to if the image were clicked on (i.e. the enclosing `<a>` tag), the ImageElement's getParent() chain can be crawled until the current Element's `getTag()` equals `AnchorElement.TAG`.  You can't do an `instanceof` test because you're working with JSO subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a DOM querying function. I'm not sure about what things look like in GWT, but jQuery was built for this. Here are some examples using that library:

```
If you're looking for...                   then call javascript...

<img id="myImg" src="foo.jpg" />           $('#myImg')
<a href="stackoverflow.com">cool</a>       $('a[href="stackoverflow.com"]')
```

Run a search on jQuery or css3 selectors for more. Hope that helps.